# Remove all rows from DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to update DataGridView in my form app, and I wrote code like below:

```cs
private void UpdateTable(DataList newDataList)
{
  this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

  foreach (Data data in newDataList)
    this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(data.Name, data.Value);
}
```

And when I was debugging, I noticed that the memory usage increased when adding rows.
I want the old rows to be removed from memory, since they are not referenced after they are deleted, but they will continue to remain in memory.

Is there an effective way to do it?
(Or am I misunderstanding something?)

Comment: The garbage collector isn't instant.

Comment: I have used the debugger to confirm that the garbage collection has been run many times, but it does not reduce memory usage.

Comment: In short, that's ok. To be sure just learn as more as you can about how does really garbage collection works. For test you may run the clean+add loop, for example 1000 times, and you'll see that after some execution, GC will reduce the amount of consumed memory. Thus you'll not get x1000 of memory, dedicated to the app. Bound memory can be free too. GC doesn't make it unbound immediately because allocating memory from OS is slower operation than reusing already bound one. [Fundamentals of garbage collection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Am I correct in understanding that if there is enough memory to use, it is not strange that unused memory is not released when the GC is executed? I would like to learn more about GC.

Comment: Do not add data to a datagridview, add it to a bindable container (DataTable, List<T>) and bind the grid to it. Go learn more about the GC; hopefully you will come to the conclusion that you should mostly leave it alone to do its work when it chooses